# How a can post a list of itens from Angular to Express + Mongodb API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm doing a Express Mongo API and that is consumed by an Angular app.

My question is about post a list of itens.

That is my mongo Scheme:

```
var TestSchema   = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  colors: {
    name: String,
    hex: Number
  }
});
```

How a i can post an array to colors?

I tried make on this way:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test.colors[0].name">
<input type="text" ng-model="test.colors[1].name">
<input type="text" ng-model="test.colors[2].name">
```

But, is posting something like that and does not work:

```
{"1":{"colors":"red"},"2":{"colors":"blue"},"3":{"colors":"green"}}
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your colors to be an array of objects you should change your Schema definition:

```
var TestSchema   = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  colors: [{
    name: String,
    hex: Number
  }]
});
```

Than you can bind your input to some function which will push colors to test.colors array:

```
<input type="text" id="colorName" />
<input type="button" value="Insert color" onclick="insert()" />

function insert() {
   var color = {
      name: document.getElementById("colorName");
   };

   test.colors.push(color);
}
```

Comment: But still not working. I think the issue is with the data of the form:
{"1":{"colors":"red"},"2":{"colors":"blue"},"3":{"colors":"green"}}

Comment: Have you tried to use push method to insert values into array?

Answer (score 0):

*You can try it*

**In HTML:**

```
Color name: <input type="text" id="color" ng-model="color.name" />
Hex value: <input type="text" id="hex" ng-model="color.hex" />
<button type="button" ng-click="addColor()">Add color with code</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="saveColorInfo()">Save color info </button> <!--to send to DB -->
```

**In controller:**

```
$scope.color = {};

$scope.test = {};
$scope.test.title= 'test name';
$scope.test.colors = [];

$scope.addColor = function() {
   $scope.test.colors.push($scope.color);
};

$scope.saveColorInfo = function() {
   console.log($scope.test); // output will be like-> {title: 'test name', colors: [{name:"black", hex: "#fff"},{name:"red", hex: "#ddd"}]}
   $http.post('/saveTestColor', $scope.test);// call your api
};
```

**And your schema should be:**

```
var TestSchema   = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  colors: [{
    name: String,
    hex: String
  }]
});
```